# Stripe.js error with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, stripe-payments

I seem to be having a problem with Stripe.js and I am using Laravel as a framework with cashier.

I'm using stripe.js so I don't pass and credit card data through my server and also so I don't store any either. As of the current time, there seems to be an issue with browsers. Let me explain further, Chrome works and Firefox, Internet Explorer doesn't.

**On Chrome:**
Currently when you submit the field, the form behaves as expected. It will show card errors when you press the submit button. For example, the card number, expire month, etc (it validates it).

**On Firefox and IE:**
The form will not verify, instead it says:

```
A network error has occurred, and you have not been charged. Please try again.
```

And will automatically submit the form and not tell if the card number is accepted, etc. Also when you submit the form, it goes straight to a Laravel error page that says:

```
Missing required param: card
```

and I think this means that the stripe.js is not fully being used, and maybe the form isn't paying attention the the custom js.

**Stripe.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_HdoLAxfuWl53vjchF01fMphS');

    $('#subscription-form button').on('click', function() {
        var form                    = $('#subscription-form');
        var submit                  = form.find('button');
        var submitInitialText       = submit.text();

        submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Just one moment...');

        Stripe.card.createToken(form, function(status, response) {
            var token;
            if(response.error) {
                form.find('.stripe-errors').text(response.error.message).show();
                submit.removeAttr('disabled');
                submit.text(submitInitialText);
                return false;
            } else {
                token = response.id;
                form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="token">').val(token));
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You may go try out the app at http://account.mcjoin.us and better direct me with the possible issue. And always, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my issue was quite obvious; Internet Explorer and Firefox have not depreciated the e.preventDefault();

This may be confusing, but let me explain. On Chrome, e.preventDefault() is not necessary, and what it does is prevent the default form function. On Internet Explorer or Firefox, if this is not present, Javascript will not be able to "hijack" the form and do what it needs to do. Therefor, adding e.preventDefault() will make it so that the form doesn't have the default interaction.

Let's look further into the code now, here is stripe.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_live_DdMQOXgak0v4yS0yH7vnsHqu');

    $('#subscription-form button').on('click', function(e) {
        var form = $('#subscription-form');
        var submit = form.find('button');
        var submitInitialText = submit.text();

        submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Just one moment...');
        e.preventDefault();

        Stripe.card.createToken(form, function(status, response) {
            var token;
            if(response.error) {
                form.find('.stripe-errors').text(response.error.message).show();
                submit.removeAttr('disabled');
                submit.text(submitInitialText);
            } else {
                token = response.id;
                form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="token">').val(token));
                form.submit();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

That's it! It's just that simple!

Answer (score -1):

I took a look at your page, but it requires authentication. I suspect you're getting this result because there's a JavaScript error that only occurs on Firefox and IE that prevents the Stripe.js code from working. I'd check the error console for that. Removing all other JavaScript that might be on the page and retesting would also confirm this theory.

I'd also update your server-side code so that no charge attempt is made without having a token present.

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.